# Thumbnails on new blank tab in Google Chrome shows apps instead of websites

Tags: google-chrome, thumbnails

How can I bring the website thumbnails back in Google Chrome instead of apps that currently show?

On the new tab it used to have thumbnails of webpages you visited and allowed you to pin them. Now, it has apps and just a line with a list of recent web pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the "Most Visited" link.

There's a faint arrow to the left of the title. Click on that or the title itself.

Comment: You need to click on the most visited line, and it will show them up now.

Comment: @iKarampa - that works as well.